# How to include static resources when publishing an Atom package

Tags: npm, atom-editor

I'm working on an Atom package that requires some static resources. I was expecting the following to work:

1. Define `scripts.prepublish` in `package.json` to call a script to download the external resources
2. Publish the Atom package on atom.io with `apm publish VERSION`
3. Install the Atom package from atom.io with `apm install PKGNAME`

Unfortunately it seems the `prepublish` script is not executed,
and so the package gets installed without the static resources.

Curiously, if I install with `apm install REPOREF` instead of `apm install PKGNAME`, then the `prepublish` step gets called, and the package will have the static resources.

The relevant parts from my `package.json`:

```
  "name": "janos-ss-prepublish-demo",
  "repository": "https://github.com/janos-ss/prepublish-demo",
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": "node ./scripts/setup.js"
  },
  "files": [
    "files"
  ],
```

`files` here is the directory where `node ./scripts/setup.js` downloads the static resources, if the package is installed with `npm install`.

After publishing with `apm`, if I install the package with `apm install janos-ss-prepublish-demo`, it seems the `prepublish` step will not get executed and the package will not have the static resources.
If I install the package with `apm install janos-ss/prepublish-demo`, the `prepublish` step is executed and the package will have the static resources.
Notice the difference in the two `apm install` commands, the first uses the name of the package as published on atom.io,
the second uses a GitHub repository reference,
with my GitHub username and the name of the repository.

Installing with `apm install REPOREF` is not an option,
because it requires explicit user action, which I don't want.
I want users to be able to install the complete package from atom.io, using the natural way from the package explorer of Atom itself.

If I understand correctly [this pending pull request](https://github.com/atom/apm/issues/372) confirms that what I'm trying to do is currently not possible. I also tried to use a custom build of `apm` from the pull request, rebased on top of the official master, but it still did not work, so I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly what's going on here.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with what I'm trying to do?

Is there another way to include static resources in the package on atom.io?

My current workaround is to download the static resources after the package is installed and activated. But this is unnecessary complexity at runtime, and ugly.

A minimal reproducible package is on [GitHub](https://github.com/janos-ss/prepublish-demo/tree/v0.0.8).

Repro steps:

```
apm publish patch
apm install janos-ss-prepublish-demo
ls ~/.atom/janos-ss-prepublish-demo  # error, doesn't exist
apm install janos-ss/prepublish-demo
ls ~/.atom/janos-ss-prepublish-demo  # exists
```